# psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied⁠?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, pgadmin

Resulta que estoy tratando que mi programa obtenga datos de una base de datos generada desde pgadmin, pero no estoy consiguiendo que suceda.

Estoy intentando de que funcione esto:

```
from psycopg2 import connect
import dbconfig
cfg=dbconfig
dbname=cfg.dbname
dbhost=cfg.dbhost
dbport=cfg.dbport
dbusu=cfg.dbusu
contrasena=cfg.contrasena

##Conexion con la BD
conexion=connect("dbname="+str(dbname)+"host="+str(dbhost)+"port="+str(dbport)+"user="+str(dbusu)+"password="+(contrasena)) 

conexion=connect("dbname=uaa host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=uaa123")
```

dbconfig:

```
# Variables Iniciales
dbhost='localhost'
dbport=5432
dbusu='postgres'
dbname='uaa'
contrasena='uaa123'
```

Me sale el error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied⁠⁠⁠⁠
```

Si pueden ayudarme, agradecería muchísimo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta de esta manera, separado por comas y cada parámetro que necesites

```
psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", user="postgres", password="secret")
```